# Overriding link styling for a particular element

Tags: html, css

I know that this question has been asked here before, but none of the answers provided there seem to be working for me.

I have a stylesheet setting the color of all links to, let's just say, red. All the rest of the text on the page is plain 'ol black. I have a particular H1 element that is a link, but I do *not* want this H1 element to be red, like all other links. Instead, I just want it to be regular black, like all other text. No matter what I seem to try, though, it stays red as all other links.

This is the code I have in my stylesheet:

```
a:link {text-decoration: none; color: #B83131;}
a:visited {color: #B83131;}
```

I have tried specific styling for the specific H1 tag, but it doesn't help. I tried giving the H1 tag a class name and styling that class, but it didn't help. I feel like I am missing something here...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you set it to the anchor?

```
h1 a:link { color: black; }
```

Comment: Where am I adding that? :)

Answer (score 0):

If your markup resembles the below:

```
<h1>
   <a href="#">Bleh</a>
</h1>
```

Then you should be able to add the CSS rule as:

```
h1 a { color: #000; }
```